# Generate all the powerset of a set in javascript

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I am not able to get the correct output with my following snippet below, can't figure out the issue:

```
function powerSet(arr) {
  var res = [];
  var len = arr.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, len); i++) {
    var aux = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
      //console.log(j +':'+((1<<j) & j));
      if (((1<<j) & j) !== 0) {
        aux.push(arr[j]);
      }
    }
    res.concat(aux);
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(powerSet([1, 2])); // [[1], [2], [1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

- you should check the bis of `i` instead of `j` i.e. `i & 1 << j`
- do `res.push(aux)` instead of `res.concat(aux)`

```js
function powerSet(arr) {
  var res = [];
  var len = arr.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, len); i++) {
    var aux = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
      //console.log(j +':'+((1<<j) & j));
      if (i & (1 << j)) {
        aux.push(arr[j]);
      }
    }
    res.push(aux);
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(powerSet([1, 2])); // [[1], [2], [1, 2]]
```